# Trying to make a Low-Power detector

Tags: project

I'm trying to make a script that plays a noise when the microbit power is low, what i mean by that is that i want the microbit to detect the power left in the batteries. I know how to make it play the noise but I need it to detect the power

I did tons of research and didn't find anything